# How can I get a fragment to go under 2 other fragments? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to get a fragment to go underneath 2 other fragments, while having a fragment extending the full length of the screen on each side.

I am using a linear layout which I think is problematic, however, I tried using relative and frame layouts as well and I was unable to get them to line up the way I want them.

[Here is what is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpkD7.png)

[Here is what I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpqU1.png)

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }
}
```

**Fragment1.java (same for all 5 fragments)**

```
package fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container, false);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication.Fragment1"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:name="fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication.Fragment2"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="273dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment5"
    android:name="fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication.Fragment5"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment3"
    android:name="fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication.Fragment3"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="273dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment4"
    android:name="fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication.Fragment4"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

**fragment1.xml (same for all 5 fragments)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FF0000"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fragment 1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to create multiple liner layout like this and add fragments in this.

[image]

Comment: I hadn't thought about doing this. 

How would I make the blue and yellow fragments show over the larger green one? If I was to add content to the green fragment, wouldn't it be hidden underneath the blue and yellow fragments?

Comment: middle one is linear layout with horizontal

Comment: I do not understand this at all. Thank you for trying. =]

Answer (score 0):

easier way is nested LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_red"
        android:name="fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_blue"
                android:name="fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication.Fragment2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_yellow"
                android:name="fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication.Fragment5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_green"
            android:name="fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication.Fragment3"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_puple"
        android:name="fragmentexample.example.com.myapplication.Fragment4"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, I edited answer. blue and yellow should have same height.

Answer (score 0):

While nested LinearLayouts are bad for performance, having hard-coded dimensions looks bad too.

Try taking advantage of that `layout_weight` property to "fill the gaps" and stretch out the views.

[image: layout]

Note: Replace the FrameLayouts with the Fragment tags if you want, but you can just programmatically fill in the FrameLayout with a Fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="4">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:layout_height="0dp"
                      android:orientation="horizontal">
            <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#ffea00"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```